# One of two Holly Shrubs/Trees dead or dying

Tags: trees

I have two trees/shrubs that I am assuming are a type of Holly. I believe that they are just over 10 years old. One is healthy and the other lost almost all of its leaves this winter. The stems do not break off like a dead tree though. Is it going to come back, or when should I give up on it? The healthy one is in the foreground.

[image]

Edit: As requested, I've added a picture of the healthier bush.

[image: Picture of the healthier bush]

Comment: Please post a clearer picture of the shrub  behind the one in the foreground, preferably showing some leaves clearly. The plant in the foreground of the picture does not resemble holly, not sure what it is, although there's a hint that one of the leaves may suggest Camellia - do you have any other pictures when the plants looked healthy, with more leaves? The one on the left at the back could be a holly, but its again impossible to see it clearly. Has anything happened to the soil in that area, something been spilt or deposited there?

Comment: Did you have a warm autumn followed by a cold winter? Young growth is frost sensitive in *Camellia*

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, difficult to unravel quite what's going on here. First, the last picture shows what appears to be a sickly Camellia which has some sort of  deposit in the lower parts. Have you had any building work done recently, like on the wall or on the roof? It either looks as if something's been dropped on the plants, and probably the soil too, or the other possibility is a serious Teascale infestation - deposits are usually more visible beneath the leaves with that, but other forms of scale may be involved too. I note also there is what looks like an old root or some wood with white deposits on it behind the shrub, up against the wall - not sure what the white deposit signifies, but it might be more evidence of scale infestation, if it signifies anything.

Camellia are evergreen shrubs - there are some healthy leaves and even a bud on a lower right branch showing in the pic, so its not dead,but it is seriously suffering. Inspect the backs of the leaves and stems to check for scale - more info about scale here http://camelliashop.com/blog/controlling-tea-scale/

UPDATE - you've said the house was painted last summer, which might mean paint flakes and paint thinners, white spirit or other chemicals might all be implicated if any of that ended up in the soil, particularly where the almost dead Camellia is situated. Without knowing what went in the soil, its hard to say if its safe to remove that shrub and replant - on balance, I wouldn't, I'd wait and see if any growth begins at a later date, which would at least mean whatever might have been in the soil has now dissipated.

Still worth checking the healthier one for scale though, and if there's any present, the other one will have had it too.

Comment: The house was painted late last summer.

Comment: Just one more thing - DON'T fertilize, at all... for a year. They don't really need any anyway, if you use organic mulch such as composted materials, composted animal manure and so on, but no chemical fertilisers for the foreseeable at least...

Comment: The comment discussion from the now-deleted answer from the OP is at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54305/discussion-on-answer-by-christopher-scott-one-of-two-holly-shrubs-trees-dead-or I'm not aware of any other way to preserve it.

Comment: A lot of cement or lime based renders are highly alkali, and run-off from them will be highly alkali for some months after application. As *Camellia* require acidic conditions, this might explain the damage you've seen. Remove any remaining render from the soil, test the pH. If it is alkali, you will need to lower the pH which is feasible given the exact circumstances and scale involved here.

Comment: Paints are mostly polymer based so will tend to be fairly neutral. Thinners will are also likely to be neutral. Sugar-soap solution and paint-stripper can be highly alkaline and would be very bad news for a *Camellia*.

Comment: Unlikely to be ph problems - the healthy growth lower down in the now deleted picture testifies to that

Comment: Unfortunately, can't base my comments on a picture I can't see! Chlorosis caused by excess pH would tend affect newer growth though - increasing pH reduces solubility of metal ions (particularly iron). As iron ions are not particularly mobile within a plant, it will tend to remain in lower leaves and actively growing parts will go without.

Comment: Its still there - just in pink instead of white, below these comments, but you can also see healthy, non chlorotic leaves lower down in the second photo at the top of the thread.